# DSA using same k value, recover secret

Tags: dsa

I have two signatures $(r,s)$ and $(r,s')$. So the same $k$ is being used for generating the $r$ value.

I know that this exposes a vulnerability such that I can recover the secret $x$.

The first step I did was recovering the value $k$, but when I perform the following calculation, which should recover $k$, I get a floating point number. That should not be possible, right?

$$k = {H(m) - H(m1) \over s - s'}$$

This is the code I am executing at the moment (with given random integers):

```
H1 = 13461231346
H2 = 71238741350
p = 12356562
q = 4523458
s1 = 928473
s2 = 25287

k = (H1 - H2) / (s1 - s2)
print(k)
```

(this prints a float number, but should print an integer because k is always an integer)

I think the problem is that I perform the division. This should be almost certainly always be a float value in my opinion, because the odds that this evaluates to an integer is pretty low, right?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: We don't know how you executed the formula. Probably you're not working within the group using modular arithmetic. Please provide more information (using [edit])and note that code is allowed to be posted here if in support of a question.

Comment: It I'm not mistaken the Chaos Computer Club (CCC) in Germany posted pretty good slides on this attack when they attacked the signatures of the Sony Playstation. Was probably in a YouTube vid.

Comment: Thanks, I added the code I am executing. I found a source where this procedure is explained. I think I follow the procedure very acurately but somehow it doesn't work.

Comment: That looks like Python. If I'm not mistaken you'll have to use `//` to get an integer. If that doesn't work then you might need to find out if integer division is what was meant.

Comment: Be careful, the division is not integer division, it is modular inverse. Did you forget the modular $p$ and $q$s?

Comment: oh that sounds about right. but how do i do that? i.e. where do i have to put the modulo?

Comment: btw, thank you both for helping me...also thank you for the previous time you helped me!!

Comment: Nevermind, I solved the problem! your hint was very helping, the problem was that i did integer division, not modular inverse. bless you man ;)

Comment: @Guestlian you need to add @ and username to inform. Anyway, either write your answer with some explanations, or we should close this question.